# Blending animations in DirectX - is this technically possible?

Tags: animation, directx, hierarchy, mesh

I have an animated mesh in the .x format I've loaded with D3DXLoadMeshHierarchyFromX and have an animation controller for it. The mesh has two animations, one for walking and one for throwing where the walk animation.

Is it at all possible to blend the two animations in such a way that both animations can run together with the walk taking priority for frames below the hip while throwing animation takes priority for frames above it? If it is will the effect look convincing therefore worth pursuing? Do game developers typically blend animations in such a way to get all the different animations they wish or do they simply create multiple versions of the same animation, i.e. walking while throwing, standing while throwing, walking without throwing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set High and low priority animation tracks with ID3DXAnimationController::SetTrackPriority.  You can then blend between them using ID3DXAnimationController::SetPriorityBlend.